# External Drive Won't Show Up Even Though It's in Disk Utility

Tags: macbook-pro, external-disk, mount

[image]

My disk utility shows that the path is verified when I repair and verify the disk. It shows up fine in disk utility. But even after that, it doesn't show up on my hard drive, either on the left nav or in the main screen. I've indicated that I want hard drives to show up in Finder Preferences, to no avail.

Thoughts? Help!

Comment: A picture, with the drive selected, would be helpful.

Comment: Did you also enable to show "External Drives"?

Comment: Yes, I enabled it. Here's a picture:

Comment: (I added an image above, showing the verified path.) Disk repair gives the same response as the image above.

Comment: If you click "Mount" in the toolbar, does it mount on the desktop?

Comment: @Jamie ??? Your screenshot doesn't show any external drive.

Comment: It's the 500 GB Toshiba unit at the top left.

Comment: And @awesomebing1, thanks -- I wish. "Mount" is still greyed out. I've gone through this before, and Disk Verify and Disk Repair worked toward getting the icon back up on the home desktop screen. As is, I fear I've lost a decade of photos. :(

Answer (score 2):

That's the physical hard drive currently spinning away in your computer. What you regard as "Macintosh HD" is a software-created volume on that hard drive, containing OS X and all your files. You may have a Toshiba-made external hard drive, and something may be up with that, but as far as physical media is concerned, "500.11 GB TOSHIBA MK5065GSXF Media" and "Macintosh HD" are one and the same.

Answer (score 1):

The drive you have selected in your screenshot is your internal HD — note the line "Connection Type: Internal." *Mount* and *Eject* are grayed out because it's your System disk – it's already mounted, and you can't eject it because it's in use.

This means that your external drive isn't showing up at all in Disk Utility, which makes it a different problem. Does the drive mount on other computers?